# Use Vue instance inside data() function

Tags: vue.js

First I know its not best practice and not recommended at all, but there are really some rare cases when it might be useful. As an example I am using an external js library to display JSON content and seems the component accepts an `options` attribute. In this property there are couple of callback function I can use to validate the JSON content.

Here is the implementation:

```
<v-jsoneditor ref="editor"
              v-bind:plus="true"
              v-bind:options="options"
              height="500px"
              v-model="value"
              v-on:error="onError">

</v-jsoneditor>
```

Below is the data function.

```
data() {
    return {
        value: "",
        options: {
            mode: 'code',
            onValidate(value) { //this is the function I am talking about
                if (Vue.isRequired) {//need the Vue instance here because I can not say this.isRequered
                    console.log("required");
                }
                console.log(value);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know I can have a create method like below and use closure on the vue instance:

```
async created() {
    let vue = this;
    this.options.onValidate = function (value) {
        if (vue.isRequired) {
            console.log("required");
        }
        console.log(value);
        return null;
    }
    await this.loadRules();
}
```

but was hoping there is a better way to do it, because create method will look very convoluted if I keep adding more and more callback function like this one.

Is there any better way to access current Vue instance in the data() function ?
The lib I am using is [this](https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor/blob/master/docs/api.md#configuration-options?blank) one.

Comment: you can simplify a function declaration using an arrow function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it much easier than I thought, completely forgot about changing data() to use array function notation like below:

```
data: (vue) => ({
    value: "",
    state: null,
    errorMessage: "",
    showRulesModal: false,
    rules: [],
    options: {
        mode: 'code',
        onValidate(json) {
            let errors = [];
            if (Object.keys(json).length === 0 && vue.isRequired) {
                vue.$emit("on-value-validation-failed");
                errors.push({
                    path: [''],
                    message: 'Value is required to continue'
                })
                return errors;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}),
```

Thanks @Antoly for pointing me to the right direction :)